# Reactjs Error: "optionValues" is read-only

Tags: reactjs

Why is it I am having error  **Error: "optionValues" is read-only** ? did I do something wrong with mapping the data? or did I forget something to map the data? please help.

this is my code

```
 const [newUserLists, setNewUserLists] =useState([]);
  const fetchData = async () => {
     const response = await getUsers('Active');
     setNewUserLists(response.data.map(user => ({
       label: user.departmentname, 
       value: user.departmentname})))
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [reRender]);


const optionValues = [];
      
{newUserLists.map(({ label, value }) => (
     optionValues = [{label}]
))}

return (
     <FormControl style={{width: 300}}>
         <InputLabel htmlFor='select-multiple-chip'>
              Select User
         </InputLabel>
            <Select
              multiple
              value={filterList[index]}
              renderValue={selected => selected.join(', ')}
              onChange={event => {
                filterList[index] = event.target.value;
                onChange(filterList[index], index, column);
              }}
            >
              {optionValues.map(item => (
                <MenuItem key={item} value={item}>
                  <Checkbox
                    color='primary'
                    checked={filterList[index].indexOf(item) > -1}
                  />
                  <ListItemText primary={item} />
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
        );
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on your desired output for `optionValues `?  Firstly, you cannot assign a new value to a `const`.  Secondly, even if you use `var` or `let`, you will overwrite it each time.

Comment: `optionValues` is where i map the `newUserLists` or the data from the database

Comment: You are not using `Array.map` correctly.  You should assign it as a value to the `map` call itself, e.g.

`const optionValues = newUserLists.map(element => { return {element.value}});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `optionValues` as `let` from `const`. It is ready only because the variable is `const`.

Comment: I changed my `const` to `let` and I received this error `Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {label}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead`

Comment: optionValues is updating as array of object. If you are trying to use object to display in UI, this error will occur. try to use `item.label` like that